# How to center an image, make it act as an link and have an mouseover command?

Tags: html, css, image, hyperlink, hover

So, I'm really, really a noob when it comes to HTML/CSS, so I apologize already.

So, what I need to do, is center an image (so that it's centered also at different resolutions/screens), on mouseover change the image to another source, and also make it act as a link to another web page.

At HTML I have this:

```
<a href="url to the webpage">
<img class="Logo" src="Logo.png">
</a>
```

And at CSS I have this:

```
img.Logo{
position: absolute;
margin: auto;
left: 0; 
right: 0;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;  
}
```

So I have it nicely centered and acting as a link too, but I have absolutely no freaking idea how to make it show another image on mouseover. I'm sorry if this has been asked before or if this is a really simple question, I tried googling it out but none gave me an answer that's simple enough for me. :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a href="url to the webpage">
    <img src="Logo.png" onmouseover="this.src='your_other_image'"
      onmouseout="this.src='Logo.png'" />
</a>
```

Using **JavaScript** you can have the default image displayed before the *onmousehover* event changes the image to a second image, then back to the original upon the *onmouseout* event being triggered.

Answer (score 1):

use the css if you don't have `position: absolute`-

```
img {
margin: 0 auto;
}
```

if you want to apply `position: absolute` then use this css-

```
img {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%); /* make sure to add all the vendor prefixes */
}
```

for the mouseover effect use this JS-

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Logo')[0].onmouseover = function() {
this.src = 'yourAnotherImgUrl';
}
```

if you want to revert back to the image when mouse is out then use this JS -

```
document.getElementsByClassName('Logo')[0].onmouseout = function() {
this.src = 'yourOriginalImgUrl';
}
```